# NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, apache

Saludos, estoy trabajando en laravel 5.3 y ninguna de mis rutas funciona, la unica que funciona es la ruta raiz `'/'`, no entiendo porque.

**web.php**

```
<?php
Route::get('/',function(){
    return view("certificado.index");
});
/*Route::get("certificado",function(){
    dd("Saludos");
});*/
Route::resource("certificado",'CertificadoGarantiaController');
```

Cuando ingreso a la ruta `http://localhost/baterias/public/certificado` lo unico que me muestra es el error:

> NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161

Y asi con cualquier otra ruta que creo.

Ya intente con cosas como

> php artisan cache:clear
>     php artisan config:cache
>     composer dump-autoload
>     composer update

Y nada aun sigue saliendo el mismo error.

**Edición**
**route:list**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Error**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Ruta `'/'`**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**index de CertificadoGarantiaController**

```
public function index()
{
    dd("hola");
}
```

Comment: ¿qué muestra artisan route:list?

Comment: muestra la lista de las rutas, y existen en ella, es algo muy raro, porque el proyecto es nuevo, y apenas tengo esas rutas.

Comment: ¿No debería funcionar acaso con `http://localhost/certificado`?

Comment: cualquier `view` que muestro en la ruta raiz `'/'` se muestran como si nada, utilizo lo siguiente para ver la ruta principal `http://localhost/baterias/public/`

Comment: ¿Puedes ahora hacer un dump y mostrar el resultado de `base_path()` y `public_path()`? ¿qué servidor usas?

Comment: te refires a dump-autoload?? y utilizo apache e igual ya revise todo lo reinicie y todo y nada

Comment: No, me refiero a un dump en laravel, puede ser en el controlador de la vista que te funciona.... `dump(base_path());`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66099/discussion-between-shassain-and-shaz).

Comment: solo te falto poner Controller@"El metodo"
de nada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de discutir en el chat, logramos determinar que era una confusión de enrutamiento entre Apache y Laravel:

- Según la configuración actual, Apache esperaba que la ruta fuera `http://localhost/baterias/public/certificado`.
- Laravel esperaba que la ruta no incluyera   `/public/`.

Teniendo en cuenta que no he trabajado Laravel con Apache (solo con Nginx), planteo dos soluciones a dicho problema:

- Crear un VirtualHost en Apache para el proyecto, como lo sugieren en el siguiente enlace:

  ```
  <VirtualHost laravel.dev:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\public"
    ServerAdmin laravel.dev 
    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel">
          Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
          AllowOverride All
          Require all granted
    </Directory>
  </VirtualHost>
  ```
- Utilizar Homestead (Vagrant) o Docker para virtualizar completamente el ambiente de desarrollo y evitar inconvenientes con la máquina "local".