# Routes en laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Estimados

estoy aprendiendo laravel 5.5 y estoy probando con las rutas,

en routes/web

agregue el siguiente route

```
Route::get('/usuarios',function (){
    return 'usuarios para agregar';
});
```

para que cuando en el enlace pusiera http://miproyecto/usuarios
me devuelva el string pero en vez de eso me da un error de que la pagina no existe, estoy viendo un tutorial y el profesor lo hace de esa manera y no tiene ese inconveniente

alguna ayuda?

de ante manos muchas gracias

Comment: Mejor crea una vista, y en tu controlador, en vez de retornar ese string, mejor retorna la ruta de la vista

Comment: entiendo, pero es posible solo devolver string? no soy experto en laravel por eso pregunto

Comment: Si es posible. Bastante extraño que te falle. Lo acabo de probar y me funciona. ¿Qué error te arroja más exactamente?

Comment: tengo un virtual host, el virtual host esta linkeado  con la ruta del proyecto apuntando a la carpeta public y me direcciona a esta pantalla  que da este mensaje "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found."

Comment: Intenta acceder mejor directamente desde localhost/usuarios o la dirección 127.0.0.1 Si funciona entonces posiblemente esté mal configurado el virtualhost/config de apache y si no, posiblemente sea tu versión que ocupas.

Comment: sigue sin funcar, que version tienes tu?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72611/discussion-between-pagana-and-pablo-moraga).

Answer (score 2):

El problema parace mas de sistema que de Laravel. La URl  http://miproyecto/home funciona?

Veo dos opciones que el hosts esta mal  C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
En homestead

```
192.168.10.10  miproyecto.app
```

mejor **.app** pq **.com** puede redirigir a alguna web.

El .env en la ruta del Laravel tb puede dar problema

```
APP_URL=http://miproyecto
```

Yo te aconsejo q si estas empezando, uses HOMESTEAD.

[Documentacion Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/homestead)

Answer (score 1):

Al parecer trabajas con un servidor apache(xampp o wamp), ya que ese problema se da en ambos conjuntos confunden las rutas de laravel.
Te recomiendo algunas cosas como:

**1.-** Trabajar con [homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/homestead)

**2.-** Crear un [virtual host](https://styde.net/creando-virtual-hosts-con-apache-en-windows-para-wamp-o-xampp/)

**3.- Es poco recomendable** pero funciona correctamente y es una rapida solucion, lo que tendrias hacer es editar el `index.php` de xampp que deberia de estar en la siguiente path: **C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php**

**index.php:** Debe tener el siguiente contenido

```
<?php
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ('on' == $_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
        $uri = 'https://';
    } else {
        $uri = 'http://';
    }
    $uri .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    header('Location: '.$uri.'/dashboard/');
    exit;
?>
```

> **Lo cambias por:**

```
<?php
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ('on' == $_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
        $uri = 'https://';
    } else {
        $uri = 'http://';
    }
    $uri .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    header('Location: '.$uri.'/miproyecto/public');
    //header('Location: '.$uri.'/dashboard/'); //solo lo comentas para que no se te olvide
    exit;
//?>
```

Como se ve solo se cambio una linea codigo lo guardas y posterior a eso solo reinicias apache y tu proyecto estaria en **localhost** y listo todas las rutas funcionaran, claro que lo que ocaciona esto es que el dashboard de xammp no funcione pero se lo soluciona dejando el codigo como el original razon por la cual solo comentas esa linea.

Comment: estimado gracias por su respuesta la pondre a prueba, una consulta: configure un virtual host pero con xampp, el error igual aplica por que el problema se da con xampp'

Comment: Pues alguna de las soluciones deberia de funcionar, ya que me sucedio lo mismo pero lo solucione, te paso el [link aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/104519/notfoundhttpexception-in-routecollection-php-line-161), talvez te pueda ayudar

Answer (score 0):

Un poco tarde, pero espero poder ayudar a alguien. Tuve el mismo problema pero en mi caso yo usaba la dirección `'localhost'` y simplemente el problema era que no respete las mayúsculas que tenían los nombres de las carpetas al momento de escribir la URL, aun así podía acceder a `'public'` mostrándome la pantalla principal, pero no funciona con las rutas, escribe exactamente la **`URL`** respetando mayúsculas y quizá solucione tu problema.